# HA redis solution,cluster or Sentinel

Tags: redis

I need an HA redis solution instead of a single instance. Should I use cluster or Sentinel? I have tried to find out the difference between them, there is no official document about this, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Well, for a ***HA redis solution*** , it depends upon the number of nodes you want to configure.

According to offical Redis documentation on [Redis-cluster](https://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial) and [Redis-sentinel](https://redis.io/topics/sentinel) both provides *HA Solution* but.....

```
Redis Sentinel provides high availability for Redis. In practical terms this means that using Sentinel you can create a Redis deployment that resists without human intervention to certain kind of failures.
```

---

```
Redis Cluster provides a way to run a Redis installation where data is automatically sharded across multiple Redis nodes.

Redis Cluster also provides some degree of availability during partitions, that is in practical terms the ability to continue the operations when some nodes fail or are not able to communicate. However the cluster stops to operate in the event of larger failures (for example when the majority of masters are unavailable).
```

For more information please refer the official docs :)

Cheers